# Can I extend multiple networks over the same VPN connection?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I would like to be able to extend multiple networks between different physical locations without having to run a separate VPN connection for each network. Here's my example:

VPN Network is 192.168.1.0/24 using an OpenVPN server.

Assume 2 locations with the following setup:
ASUS router running VPN client connected to 192.168.1.0. Has clients on 192.168.10.0/24 and 192.168.20.0/24.

I would like clients on both the 192.168.10.0/24 and 20.0/24 networks at each location to be able to talk to each other over the single VPN connection that is already established from the routers. Is this possible? Can someone point me to any relevant configuration options for OpenVPN? Perhaps I'm overthinking this and it's easier than it seems?

Comment: Try this guide from the OpenVPN wiki, and come back with any specific problems you have:  https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that page, it has some good information. It doesn't quite cover what I'm looking to do though. In that example each "client" only has one LAN that is unique from the other client. In my case we have clients that are sharing the same LANs. I'd like to bridge each of those LANs between the two client locations using the same VPN connection.

Comment: So, you are saying both locations have both a `192.168.10.0/24` and a `192.168.20.0/24` network?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd like those two networks at each location to be extended over the single VPN connection, if possible. My searching has turned up examples similar to the one you linked, but nothing quite like what I'm looking for, which maybe means it isn't possible (or maybe just not feasible).

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do that.  The OpenVPN server needs to know which client to send traffic to for a particular subnet and can only have one client matching a single subnet, so the client subnets need to be unique.

Comment: Fair enough. After reading the page you linked above I was thinking that may be the case, but my knowledge of OpenVPN is limited so I wanted to get some concurrence from people who know better than I do. Thanks for taking some time to contemplate it with me. :)

Comment: You could make OpenVPNsupport this by doing bridging, but it's not practical because you will have never-ending problems with duplicate addresses. You really need to renumber one of the networks.

Comment: Thinking about it - and it's far from ideal - you might be able to get the router to map the 192.168 IPs onto other non-conflicting IP ranges on the VPN/WAN side. This could change the way machines are addressed remotely but could conceivably allow machines with duplicate IPs to communicate without conflict. It's an aweful way to do things though, and you would probably find it easier to renumber one of your networks.